# BlogEngine.NET Blank admin page

Tags: asp.net, blogs, blogengine.net

I have a blog hosted at GoDaddy on a subdomain and here is the link : [Blog](http://blog.ajeykamat.com).

Blog seems to be working fine except for the admin section. After trying to Login, admin login page loads as a Blank page : [Blog Admin Page](http://blog.ajeykamat.com/Account/login.aspx). I tried to inspect element on Chrome and it is showing partial page contents.

This blog was hosted on another site previously, I just copied content from that provider and uploaded here. On previous provider, it was working fine.

I have checked for the permission for admin folder and specifically for **web.config** and they are all good.

I tried googling it, many users seems to have had this problem but neither they nor I found a specific answer.

What can be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the page on firebug, I found something is wrong in your jquery file. It is throwing some error. I suggest you to re-upload your jquery file.

**Console Errors -**

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script
jquery-....min.js (line 3, col 17055)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
login.aspx (line 74, col 9)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
login.aspx (line 82, col 13)
```

The elements are not visible because you have this below script at the end of the page. This script is enabling the opacity of your page elements. Which means that the opacity of those elements was set to zero using css rules. That is why those elements are not visible on page load because the below script didn't executed.

```
<script>
      $(".account-header").animate({
          top: 0,
          opacity: 1,
      }, 1000);
      $(".account").animate({
          top: 0,
          opacity: 1,
      }, 1000);
</script>
```

After I removed the opacity css attribute from those elements the form started to be visible again.

[image: Image of the login form]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check this ans post a result here

Comment: I tried removing opacity property from script but it didn't worked at me. I am using Chrome btw.

Comment: I tried on FireFox too now. Removing Opacity doens't changes anything.

Comment: No.. the script is enabling the opacity, the opacity must've been set to zero in some css rule. You might wanna check for the css rules on (.account-header and .account) css classes.

Comment: account.css line no 11 and 23, remove opacity attribute or check and fix the jquery error.